# Can't find variable: casper

Tags: form-submit, casperjs

I tried to make a procedure of submitting a login form, but for some reason I can't read the value of `casper.cli.args` in the `casper.evaluate` function.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var url = 'https://www.secure.pixiv.net/login.php';

casper.start(url, function() {
    console.log("page loaded");
    //this.test.assertExists('form#login_form', 'form is found');
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("login_pixiv_id").value=(casper.cli.args[0]);
        document.getElementById("login_password").value=(casper.cli.args[1]);
        document.getElementById("login_submit").click();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) function is sandboxed. Everything has to be passed explicitly. CasperJS does inject the `__utils__` object into the page context, but not everything is accessible there like the `casper.cli` property.

You have to explicitly pass the values:

```js
casper.evaluate(function(id, password) {
    document.getElementById("login_pixiv_id").value = id;
    document.getElementById("login_password").value = password;
    document.getElementById("login_submit").click();
}, casper.cli.args[0], casper.cli.args[1]);
```

[This](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4fe2ac87193d12d3ff81) is the complete script.